# Correctly implement ng-content presence when used within ng-if

Tags: angular, angular-lifecycle-hooks, ng-content

Current code works but is surely far from ideal (I mean probably not the Angular way).

My component may or may not project external content. The *div* wrapper where the projected content will land is rendered only when one of the component's *Input*s is not undefined. A *setTimeout* call occures within the former *Input*'s setter to postpone some DOM content inspection, telling if a specific class should be applied or not, *changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()* ultimately triggers the view update accordingly.

Could someone guide me on what should be done instead?

```typescript
@Component({
    // Almost the whole the application uses OnPush change detection strategy
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    template: `
    <!-- … -->
    <div #footer *ngIf="parameters"> <!-- the wrapper -->
      <ng-content select="'.external-buttons"></ng-content> <!-- injected content -->
    </div>
    `
})
export class cardComponent {
    @HostBinding('class.hasInjectedButtons') hasInjectedButtons: boolean;
    @ViewChild('footer') footer: ElementRef;

    @Input() set data(payload: wsDataScheme) {
        // …
        // Attempt to check whether the CSS class should be applied
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.hasInjectedButtons = this.footer
                ? this.footer.nativeElement.querySelector('.external-buttons') 
                : false
            ;
            this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
        });
    }
}
```

I feel confused about Angular lifecycle resolution process dispite having read few articles using graphs like the one down below. I expected the "footer" *ViewChild* to be populated and accessible when the `ngAfterViewCheck` gets executed but it seems it's not. Playing around with lifecycle hook *ngAfterContentCheck* and *ngOnChanges* did not helped me either, nor *ContentChild* projected content reference decorator.

[image: Angular lifecycle hooks order]

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you are trying to do but If you want to figure out if the ng-content is in the DOM, use a viewchild setter which will be triggered as soon as it exists.

Comment: There is a difference between _view DOM_ and _content DOM_, view DOM gives access to elements declared within the component template itself whereas the _content DOM_ refers to "projected" elements, (elements belonging to/declared into a upper component in the tree) and which happens to be rendered in the former component. `<!-- parent context --><child-with-projected-content><projected-item>project-text</projected-item></child-with-projected-content>`)